# Using perl to split file in flat text

Tags: perl

I have a flat file that are created with offsets e.g. row 1: char 1 - 3 = ID, 4-19 = user name, 20 - 40 = last name, etc...

What's the best way to go about creating a perl script to read this?  and is there any way to make it flexible based on different offset groups?  Thank you!

Comment: Hi. Stack Overflow's about helping you solve your coding problems, rather than being a 'write my code for me' service. Why not give it a try, and see where you get stuck, then ask specifically about that?

Comment: Consider using `unpack`.

Answer (score 1):

If the positions/lengths are in terms of Unicode Code Points:

```
# Use :encoding(UTF-8) on the file handle.

my @fields = unpack('A3 A16 A21', $decoded_line);
```

If the positions/lengths are in terms of bytes:

```
use Encode qw( decode );

sub trim_end(_) { $_[0] =~ s/\s+\z//r }

# Use :raw on the file handle.

my @fields =
   map trim_end(decode("UTF-8", $_)),
      unpack('a3 a16 a21', $encoded_line);
```

In both cases, trailing whitespace is trimmed.